# How can I show a loading/splash screen while CSV is being error checked - C# WinForms?

Tags: c#, winforms, thread-safety

I have a C# WindowsForm application that reads a CSV file and filters out any "errors" that occur within the file. The app then allows the user to filter through the data through specific filters (i.e. Suburbs). The form displays once the errors have been filtered. However, this takes several seconds. During this time I would like to display a splash/loading screen to show that the application is loading.

I have created a Thread that displays the splash screen, however, the following error is thrown on the code displayed below.

> System.ComponentModel.InvalidAsynchronousStateException: 'An error occurred invoking the method.  The destination thread no longer exists.'

```cs
private void UpdateLabel(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Thread.CurrentThread.IsAlive)
            {
                if (lblLoading.InvokeRequired)
                {
                    if (count == 0)
                    {
                        lblLoading.Invoke(new Action(() => lblLoading.Text = "Loading."));
                        count++;
                    }
                    else if (count == 1)
                    {
                        lblLoading.Invoke(new Action(() => lblLoading.Text = "Loading.."));
                        count++;
                    }
                    else if (count == 2)
                    {
                        lblLoading.Invoke(new Action(() => lblLoading.Text = "Loading..."));
                        count++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        lblLoading.Invoke(new Action(() => lblLoading.Text = "Loading"));
                        count = 0;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (count == 0)
                    {
                        lblLoading.Text = "Loading.";
                        count++;
                    }
                    else if (count == 1)
                    {
                        lblLoading.Text = "Loading..";
                        count++;
                    }
                    else if (count == 2)
                    {
                        lblLoading.Text = "Loading...";
                        count++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        lblLoading.Text = "Loading";
                        count = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Even prior to updating the label, the splash screen would close prior to the error checking.

Thanks, nozzy

Comment: Why not just use backgroundworker ?

Comment: @confusedMind what is that?

Comment: in Windows form you can use a backgroundworker see it in tool box it has  onprogress and oncomplete and you can pass on to it like:

backgroudworker.reportprogress(0,"something");   and you can send 0,1,2,3 and show different output based on that etc.

Comment: @confusedMind would that work if im using 2 forms (the splash having its own)... and the error checking occurring on the main form load?

Comment: Dont think should be an issue but you can check just call the splash form and run the backgroundworker and on complete hide the splash form should be simple.

Comment: [This](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?888203) may be of interest to you. It is a ready-made dialogue that incorporates the use of a `BackgroundWorker`. You can write the code in your form to do the background work and then display the dialogue and have it invoke that code via events.

Answer (score 0):

Use backgroundWorker in Winform code willbe something like:

On button Click:

```
//SHOW YOUR SCREEN
backgrounWorker.Runasync();

 private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
// here you can call :
       backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(0,"abc");
       backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(2,"abc");
}
    private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {// show your progress here
    if(e.progresspercentage==0){
            listBox3.Items.Insert(0, e.UserState.ToString());
            listBox3.Update();}  
        }

   private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
         //remove splash screen here
        }
```

Comment: Can this be done on FormLoad?

Comment: Nowadays you should solve that with tasks and `IProgress<T>`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base example for [IProgress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iprogress-1?view=net-7.0) mentioned by @Sir Rufo.

[image]

Coded with .NET Core 7
No exception handling yet you need to add this especially when working with files.

Mockup for performing work, in this case Task.Delay is to be replaced with your work.

```
public class Operations
{
    public static async Task PerformWork(IProgress<int> progress, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {

        for (int index = 0; index <= 100; index++)
        {
            // Simulate an async call that takes some time to complete
            await Task.Delay(100, cancellationToken);

            if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            }

            progress?.Report(index);
        }
    }
}
```

MainForm displays a secondary form in the Shown event, feel free to change to the Load event.

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Shown += MainForm_Shown;
    }

    private void MainForm_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SplashForm splashForm = new();
        try
        {
            if (splashForm.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                // work completed
            }
            else
            {
                // user cancelled
            }

        }
        finally
        {
            splashForm.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Splash form, note ReportProgress updates a progressbar, could also be a label. Also, there is a button for cancellation would you may not want.

```
public partial class SplashForm : Form
{
    private readonly CancellationTokenSource 
        _cancellationTokenSource = new();
    public SplashForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Shown += SplashForm_Shown;
    }

    private async void SplashForm_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        var cancelled = false;
        var progressIndicator = new Progress<int>(ReportProgress);

        try
        {
            await Operations.PerformWork(
                progressIndicator, 
                _cancellationTokenSource.Token);

            // indicates success to main form and closes this form
            DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException ex)
        {
            cancelled = true;
        }

        if (cancelled)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Cancelled");
            // indicates user cancelled to main form and closes this form
            DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Update progress bar from Operations.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value"></param>
    private void ReportProgress(int value)
    {
        progressBar1.Increment(1);
    }
    private void CancelOperationButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
    }
}
```